# Homemade alcohol

Tags: alcohol, distillation

As you know  with the ongoing corona-virus issue, the need of alcohol as a disinfectant had increased dramatically.

I live in Iran, where alcohol is illegal. Nowadays, even if you can find a 100cc of 70% ethanol, you can expect to pay x10 price.

I'm looking for a way to make 70% alcohol with simple things that may find in any kitchen for daily needs.

Comment: Try posting this question at https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/

Comment: in addition to alcohol, you need glycerin or aloe vera to keep your hands from drying out

Answer (score 3):

To make it with "simple things that may find in any kitchen for daily needs" is not possible to my knowledge. However you can with a few pieces bits that you should be easily able to get your hands on.

For example [this recipe I found online](https://www.offthegridnews.com/how-to-2/the-survivalists-simple-guide-to-making-rubbing-alcohol-from-scratch/) :

- Roughly 2 pounds of white sugar (preferably not bleached).
- 1 gallon of water, purified if possible.
- 2 empty water jugs made of HDPE plastic (simply look at the mark on the bottom of the jug), or a glass drinking jug.
- 1 jar of simple baker’s yeast.
- About 2 ½ feet of coiled copper tubing (not as expensive as you might think).
- A bowl of cold water or ice big enough to hold your container (this is not a
  necessary step but it helps speed up the process).
- 1 thermometer.
- 1 funnel.
- Duct tape.

Note that it does take over 2 weeks.